# Web Page: How to update a portion of web page when it changes?

Tags: html

I'm actually very new to Web Page Development and would like to have a simple (offline) HTML page displaying in a Control or Browser itself.

Target is to make a log viewer page, which is constantly updating through another application, (which I'm writing in C# plus some Powershell coding).

It might be divided into frames containing different pages, or one page containing different areas.

Main purpose is to update the changes immediately. E.g. If you are viewing the web page, and my application change the Text at some areas of that page, it should detect the change and immediately update that area.

How to achieve this? Is HTML 5 got any such methodologies which are easy to use?

I'm open to any suggestions... And thanks a lot in advance...

Comment: What exactly are you hoping to achieve? TO update a part of a webpage without refreshing you would normally use AJAX...

Comment: Use Ajax http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)

Answer (score 3):

You can't do this with HTML5 as far as I know.

To create the Dynamic log viewer page , you can use ajaxticker.js.
It is easy to use..

[Ajaxticker Tutorial and Demo](http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/ajaxticker/index.shtml)

Comment: Sounds like a working thing.. But this involves server as well. I want an offline page, with possibly inline HTML 5 or JavaScript kind of thing.
I know we can check for updates on small time interval base, but are there any events (like UpdateWebPage or PageChange) to detect and load in DIV areas?

Comment: You can use web-sockets which are two way communication between client and server that remain open and allow the server to send without request from the client. However web-sockets are new and browser support is only for the most current browsers.

[**socket.io**](http://socket.io) is a great library for web sockets with fall backs to AJAX and flash if they are not supported.

**Source** : [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9958165/can-web-server-send-data-without-a-request-from-client](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9958165/can-web-server-send-data-without-a-request-from-client)